# Visual Studio Deletes Build Output From Other Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, buildconfiguration

I have a Visual Studio 2010 VC++ Solution/Project that has four build configurations: 32-bit Debug, 64-bit Debug, 32-bit Release, and 64-bit Release.  The output for each of these builds is saved in its own folder: Debug, Debug64, Release, or Release64.  When all four builds succeed all is well with the world.  However, when any one of the builds fails, Visual Studio deletes the final output files from the previous builds, even though they are in different folders!  Does anyone know how to prevent this in Visual Studio?  I'd prefer to learn to use Visual Studio correctly, rather than implement some clunky workaround outside the IDE (including post-build scripts) that may or may not be well understood or received by my peers.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using 'batch build'? Can you increase MSBuild verbosity level and inspect the results?

Comment: No, not using batch build.  How do I increase the verbosity for MSBuild?

Comment: tools/optios/projects/build and run, iirc.